# Katalon Studio mock services?

Tags: soap, soapui, rest-assured, katalon-studio

Can  I mock/virtualize web services using Katalon Studio like WireMock or CA DevTest or Soap UI? If so, how can I do it , I didn’t find it on their site.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not yet available in Katalon Studio, but it is planned in the 2018 roadmap.

[Katlon Studio - Roadmap 2018](https://forum.katalon.com/discussion/5747/roadmap-and-voting-for-your-features)